# Цикл PHP и Html код

Tags: php, html, циклы

Здравствуйте,такая проблема: нужно вставить в цикл PHP отрисовку линий из Html, но чего-то не хватает. Подскажите как это правильно реализовать?

```
<? for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
echo $i;

<polyline points="<? echo $x ?>,<? echo $y+$h ?>
                  <? echo $x*$l ?>,<? echo $y+$h ?>
                  <? echo $x*$l+$dx ?>, <? echo $y+$dy+$h ?>
                  <? echo $x*$l ?>, <? echo $y+2*$dy+$h ?>
                  <? echo $x ?>, <? echo $y+2*$dy+$h ?>
                  <? echo $x-$dx ?>, <? echo $y+$dy+$h ?>
                  " id="silfon" fill=gray stroke="#4D5656" stroke-width="1" >
    <animateTransform 
             begin="startButton.click"
             attributeType="XML"
             attributeName="transform"
             type="scale"
             from="1 1"
             to="1 2"
             dur="2s"
             fill="freeze">
 </polyline>
} ?>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы он нарисовал 5 ($i) таких фигур с установленным отступом ($h) от предыдущих

Comment: В чем проблема-то конкретно? Ошибки есть? тогда добавьте их в вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [Альтернативный синтаксис управляющих структур](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) .

В Вашем случае у Вас ошибка синтаксиса, вот так будет правильней:

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++): ?>
<?php echo $i; ?>
<polyline points="<? echo $x ?>,<? echo $y+$h ?>
                  <? echo $x*$l ?>,<? echo $y+$h ?>
                  <? echo $x*$l+$dx ?>, <? echo $y+$dy+$h ?>
                  <? echo $x*$l ?>, <? echo $y+2*$dy+$h ?>
                  <? echo $x ?>, <? echo $y+2*$dy+$h ?>
                  <? echo $x-$dx ?>, <? echo $y+$dy+$h ?>
                  " id="silfon" fill=gray stroke="#4D5656" stroke-width="1" >
    <animateTransform 
             begin="startButton.click"
             attributeType="XML"
             attributeName="transform"
             type="scale"
             from="1 1"
             to="1 2"
             dur="2s"
             fill="freeze">
 </polyline>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 0):

Код сценария начинается после открывающего тэга `<?` и заканчивается закрывающим `?>`, оставил в коментариях отсутствия тэга

`<? for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    echo $i;
?>//нужно закрывающий тэг Для того что бы закончить код сценария PHP
    <polyline points="<? echo $x ?>,<? echo $y+$h ?>
                  <? echo $x*$l ?>,<? echo $y+$h ?>
                  <? echo $x*$l+$dx ?>, <? echo $y+$dy+$h ?>
                  <? echo $x*$l ?>, <? echo $y+2*$dy+$h ?>
                  <? echo $x ?>, <? echo $y+2*$dy+$h ?>
                  <? echo $x-$dx ?>, <? echo $y+$dy+$h ?>
                  " id="silfon" fill=gray stroke="#4D5656" stroke-width="1" >
    <animateTransform
             begin="startButton.click"
             attributeType="XML"
             attributeName="transform"
             type="scale"
             from="1 1"
             to="1 2"
             dur="2s"
             fill="freeze">
 </polyline>
<?//а тут нужен открывающий тэг
 } ?>`